# Tor Browser Bundle default HTTP headers

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

Would you guys kindly show me your TBB's HTTP headers?
I'm using Privoxy, a Tor (SOCKS5) HTTP proxy software.
I must use it to use some of software that doesn't support SOCKS protocol.

I want to configure Privoxy to speak the same way TBB do.

Please show me your TBB's:
All of `HTTP_*` data, such as `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is asking about default HTTP headers in Tor Browser Bundle. Here they are:

```
Accept:             text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:    en-us,en;q=0.5
User-Agent:         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case: Tor+ Privoxy + Iceweasel(Browser)
actually the browser doesn't matter to configure privoxy

copy in the privoxy's file "user.action" :

{+hide-accept-language{en-ca} \
  +hide-user-agent{Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; OpenBSD i386; en-CA; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060628 Firefox/1.5.0.4} \

}

/

Comment: between the main text , the last '}' and the last '/' the the is no an empty line. i just couldn't edit it